# Is this a bad engine mount?

Tags: engine, mazda-3, hood

So it's my first time opening the hood of my car, only to find this. I came to ask because this doesn't look normal, I dont know any reason what could cause this as its a new unit, 600 kms on my odo as well as I've barely driven the car due to lockdown.  What caused this?

[image]

Comment: If the car really only has 600 kilometers on it, your motor mount is unlikely to be bad. Looks fine in the picture.

Comment: "What caused this?" define "this" your question is unclear

Comment: @Moab there is some crud on the casing where the engine mount is attached. Whatever it is, it didn't come from nowhere and it probably wasn't there when the engine was first built.

Comment: If the vehicle only has 600 km on it, take it to the dealership and have them inspect it. If there's an issue, it should be under warranty and will get replaced for free. As for the crud which is on there. it *might* have come from the motor mount. Very well could be it's from something else. Either way, if you're worried about it, let the dealership earn their money. Take it in and have them look at it.

Comment: Rule #1: Always inspect under the hood before purchasing any powered vehicle... and immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it’s something on the engine mount from the manufacturing process from that component manufacturer. My guess is it’s spilled hydraulic filler used in their process.  Note I see that same brown spray in other areas of that mount, and only on the mount.

I concur with Paulsters assessment. Have the dealership review. Do not feel bad about asking that the part be tested good at the dealer with verification or replaced immediately. The factory should not be sending out parts that look like that.

You can also ask the parts counter at the dealership if you could inspect a new engine mount. Does a new part display the same brown overspray?

Comment: Thanks will do as advised. Had to ask because service centers here are taking time to open and our area is still on lockdown.